# Неправильное отображение координат пикселей windows

Tags: python, mouse-event

Пишу программу с использованием управления мышью, для этого использую модуль mouse.
Проблема заключается в том, что координаты полученные и от mouse, и от win32api выходят ошибочные, и неточные, что мешает правильной работе программы(
Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: `выходят ошибочные, и неточные`  - как вы это узнали?

Comment: При управлении курсором, курсор смещался по другим координатам

Answer (score 0):

Убираете увеличение экрана и все работает точно